# Click Event on list item does not fire properly(iOs 6 only)

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios6

This is my first post on Stack Overflow. I have searched google for a solution to this issue and have tried many workarounds but to no avail. Here is my case.Please note that this code is running fine on iOs 5 on a client iPads. My issue is only with iOs 6

I have a ul tag and within that I have multiple list items and on clicking each list item I would navigate the usetr to a different page.Please look at the code below.Sorry if the code is not formatted. I am in such a hurry.

```
<ul class="tp-breadcrumb" style="float: left; width:91%;">
        <li class="current"><a href="#" style="padding-top:8px;height:23px" class="ui-link">Definition</a></li>
        <li id="brdDateTimeRepSpeaker"><a style="padding-top:1px;height:30px" class="ui-link">Date, Rep,<br>Speaker</a></li>
        <li id="brdVenueManagement"><a style="padding-top:8px;height:23px" class="ui-link">Venue</a></li>
        <li id="brdAudienceSupport"><a style="padding-top:8px;height:23px" class="ui-link">Audience</a></li>
        <li id="brdSummary"><a style="padding-top:8px;height:23px" class="ui-link">Summary</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to fire the click for the list item(The anchor tag is a blank one with href="#"). **It will fire the first time. But after navigating to another page and then coming back, the click event is not firing.**

**However, if I click on a textbox or any other control on the page and then click the list item the click is firing fine the second time.Below is the click code**

```
$("#brdVenueManagement").live("click", function () {
    alert('click');

});
```

I have tried the following.

- Adding an onclick="" handler to the list item
- Moving the click event to the hyper link instead of the list item and
  specifying   onclick="" and href="#"
- Have tried tap and touchstart events.
- Giving focus to the (Since my li's are dynamically generated)

In all of the above cases it works fine before navigating to another page. On coming back, the click is fired only if i click on some control in the page and then click the list item

Please help me out here guys. I am at a loss as to why this is not working on iOS 6. Its working fine on desktop browsers as well as iPads with iOs5 or lower.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind,

I fixed it myself. It was a position:relative on my li that was causing the events not to fired. I removed it and everything's fine.

Sriram